# REST API for Autoscaling in Bluemix doesn't have policyTriggers defined?

Tags: ibm-cloud, autoscaling

I need to configure autoscaling via REST API or atleast ensure that the policy configuration is picked from a file location. The only method I see now to configure it is through the UI. In the [REST API](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/apidocs/48) the policyTriggers are not defined and I don't see a way to configure it via any file based configuration also.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the document site is under maintenance and so many definition of information element that BlueMix Auto-scaling REST API are using are missing. PolicyTriggers is an array of PolicyTrigger which including the following item (in json format):
== ==

```
                policyTriggers   -  List<Trigger>    -  Required - Trigger setting for this policy, each trigger is defined as below 
                 metricType             -  String -  Required - enumerated type for this trigger, for Java application, they are: JVMHeapUsage, Memory, Throughput, ResponseTime. For other app, only Memory is available.
                 statWindow             -  int    -  Optional - interval to calculate statistics in seconds 
                 breachDuration         -  int    -  Optional - breach duration in seconds is divided by the periodicity of the metric to determine the number of data points that will result in a scaling event
                 lowerThreshold         -  int    -  Optional - lower threshold that will trigger a scaling event, usually scaling-in, for JVMHeapUsage and Memory it's percentage, for Throughput, it's request per second and for ResponseTime, it's milliseconds
                 upperThreshold         -  int    -  Optional - upper threshold that will trigger a scaling event, usually scaling-out. for JVMHeapUsage and Memory it's percentage, for Throughput, it's request per second and for ResponseTime, it's milliseconds
                 instanceStepCountDown  -  int    -  Optional - number of instances to reduce per scaling-in action
                 instanceStepCountUp    -  int    -  Optional - number of instances to increase per scaling-out action
                 stepDownCoolDownSecs   -  int    -  Optional - cool down period that prevent further scaling in action
                 stepUpCoolDownSecs     -  int    -  Optional - cool down period that prevent further scaling out  action
```

Alternative way to create a policy is using Auto-scaling CLI(https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/plugins/auto-scaling/index.html), you can open saved policy file and see the structure of PolicyTriggers.